# Is there any basis for ‪Transversal‬ matrix space?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, latin-square, transversality

Given That An N-By-N Matrix A, Is A Set Of Numbers With One From Each Row And Each Column Is Called A Transversal Matrix

1. Given that an n-by-n matrix A, is a set of numbers with one from each row and each column is called a transversal matrix. We say that A is a constant transversal matrix if all transversals have the same sum. If matrices A and B have the constant transversal property, then so do A+B and cA, for any constant c. Therefore it follows that the set of constant transversal matrices forms a vector space Vn. Also, the set Bn = {R_2, R_3,...R_n, C_1, C_2,..., Cn} spans Vn.

a) Show that if a row is constant of a transversal matrix then all the matrix rows are constant.

b) Let R_k be a n x n matrix in which each entry of the kth row is 1 and all other entries are 0. Show that this is a basis for the vector space Vn.

Comment: Part b) doesn't seem right. How is $\pmatrix{1&2\cr1&2\cr}$ a linear combination of $\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&0\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{0&0\cr1&1\cr}$?

Comment: Accroding to transversal matrix definition \pmatrix{1&2\cr1&2\cr} is not a transversal matrix  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransversalArray.html

Comment: The matrix $\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}$ has exactly two transversals, $\{a,d\}$ and $\{b,c\}$, so it's a constant transversal matrix if and only if $a+d=b+c$. So $\pmatrix{1&2\cr1&2\cr}$ is a constant transversal matrix. I don't see what the mathworld link has to do with anything, it just defines transversal, not "transversal matrix".

Comment: Transversal matrix : For a square matrix A of order n, is n entries whose no two are same in a row or column

Comment: That's the definition of a transversal, not a transversal matrix. And, as I have said, if $n=2$ then there are exactly two transversals. How can it be that $\pmatrix{1&1\cr2&2\cr}$ qualifies but the matrix I gave doesn't?

Comment: Oh, thanks because your kindness!